How to Estimate Time in Depth-First Traversal with Dynamic Pruning?
I am performing a depth-first traversal of a tree with n levels (input size of the problem), where each node has B (e.g. B=16) branches. This means I could potentially explore a total of B^n possible configurations.
I achieve uniformly an average pruning rate of P% (e.g., 93.75%) on large n, where this percentage is calculated as the ratio of branches discarded to branches visited. [It is important to note that the pruning percentage is computed dynamically, which results in a compounding effect—meaning I am not simply visiting a fraction (1 - P) of configurations over the entire traversal.]
Given that each branch takes time T to explore, how can I estimate the total time and the computation complexity required for the traversal process, accounting for the dynamic nature of the pruning?

As you very well pointed out, pruning at a node at level $i$ you affect all nodes below it.
Let us denote $c_n$ the expected number of traversed nodes if you would start at level $n$ and $p$ the probability to prune any node upon discovery. Hence, at the root we have $$c_0=p+\underbrace{(1-p)B}_q\cdot c_1+(1-p)=1+qc_1\,,$$
because with probability $p$ we prune and traverse no further nodes, whereas with the complement we have to i) process the current node and then ii) repeat this procedure for each of the $B$ branches. For the sake of simplicity, here we also set $q:=(1-p)B$.
This gives a recursive formula, which is linear in the previous count. We can thus write
$$\left[\begin{array}{c}1\\c_n\end{array}\right]=A\left[\begin{array}{c}1\\c_{n+1}\end{array}\right]\,,\quad A=\left[\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\1&q\end{array}\right]\,.$$
Now, the full expectation you are looking for can be extracted by the second element of the vector
$$\left[\begin{array}{c}1\\c_0\end{array}\right] = A^n\left[\begin{array}{c}1\\c_n\end{array}\right]\,.\quad(1)$$
In the above we can set $c_n=1$ as at the $n$-th level, we only need to process a single node.
We can now compute the expectation analytically by Eq. (1). The characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $A-\lambda I=(1-\lambda)(q-\lambda)$ and its eigenvalues $\lambda_1=1$, $\lambda_2=q$. Further, the matrix $A$ is diagonalisable as (according to my symbolic software)
$$ A=S\Lambda S^{-1}=
\left[\begin{array}{cc}1-q&0\\1&1\end{array}\right]\cdot
\left[\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\0&q\end{array}\right]\cdot
\left[\begin{array}{cc}\frac 1{1-q}&0\\\frac{-1}{1-q}&1\end{array}\right]\,,
$$
and so
$$ A^n\left[\begin{array}{c}1\\1\end{array}\right]=S\Lambda ^nS^{-1}\mathbb 1=
\left[\begin{array}{c}1\\c_0\end{array}\right]
\,,
$$
with
$$c_0=\frac{q^{n+1}-1}{q-1}\,;\quad(2)$$
Note that if we used $c_n=0$, the exponent in the numerator of Eq. (2) would be $n$ instead of $n+1$.
Now let's see what we got, and let's do this rigorously. I claim that for $p>\frac{B-1}B$ we have (asymptotically) exponential complexity. To show this, we compute the limit of $c_n$ over an exponential function
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac {c_0(n)}{q^n}=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{q^{n+1}-1}{q-1}}{q^n}=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{q^{n+1}-1}{q^n(q-1)}=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{q^{n+1}\big(1-\frac1{q^{n+1}}\big)}{q^{n+1}\big(1-\frac1{q^n}\big)}=1\,,
$$
so we have $c_0\sim q^n$, that is, it is asymptotically equal to an exponential.
When $p=\frac {B-1} B$ the average complexity becomes linear. Indeed,
$$\lim_{p\to\frac{B-1}B} c_0(n,p)=
\lim_{p\to\frac{B-1}B} \frac{\big((1-p)B\big)^{n+1}-1}{(1-p)B-1}=
\lim_{p\to\frac{B-1}B} \frac{\partial_p\Big[\big((1-p)B\big)^{n+1}-1\Big]}{\partial_p\big[(1-p)B-1\big]}=
\lim_{p\to\frac{B-1}B} \frac{-(n+1)(1-p)^nB^{n+1}}{-B}=
(n+1)\lim_{p\to\frac{B-1}B} (1-p)^nB^n=n+1\,.
$$
Finally, when $p<\frac{B-1}B$, the complexity becomes constant, O(1), since
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}c_0(n)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{q^{n+1}-1}{q-1}=\frac1{1-q}\,.$$
Just to make sure, I did run some simulations, and the theoretical expectation matches the experimental values. Note, however, that the variance of the number of traversed nodes is quite high (though bounded, as the total number of nodes is huge but bounded).
Here are simulations of 10000 runs per point, for a branching factor of $b=2$. The shaded ribbons are quantiles, the line is the theoretical value of Eq. (1) and the points averages of each simulation. The distribution is highly skewed, so the median is far from the mean (and, of course, the symmetric quantiles do not necessarily contain the mean). Plotted save values in linear and log-scales.



Thank you, Janis! I will need some time to digest all that: the computation is more complex than I expected. So, from what I begin to understand, in order to achieve, say, a polynomial time, I need more than a constant pruning rate. Perhaps a "decisively declining" pruning rate. However, right now, I cannot quantify that with a specific function. If you have a suggestion, feel free to add to your beautiful answer. Thank you!

"increasing"  :-)

Considering that the main term seems to be (B (1-p) )^n for asymptotic matters, I guess that for p > (B-1)/B we may approach a decent time. For instance for  p > 15/16 = 94%, in case B=16 (which is pretty close to what I have at the moment,  and I can possibly improve).

I am plotting 16(1-0.9375)^x, my actual current simulation data, on Desmos, and actually, it gives me a straight line (?). So I have to interpret this as an almost constant time or what ? How is this kind of time called?

@Jada You are perfectly right! I oversaw this. I also changed the initial (terminal?) condition to $c_0=0$, which makes the result significantly cleaner, and esp. because of introducing a $q$ symbol for $(1-p)B$. There might be simpler ways to arrive to this, but I think this is a fairly accurate and flexible one. As for the complexity, I am not too confident on the names; in the case of $q=1$ it would not be really constant time, but average constant time. For practical reasons, you can treat them the same; in theory, I am not sure.

Thank you Janis for helping me understand better the matter. I am very grateful. I guess I will have to work more on pruning and simulation to understand better the real nature of this. Constant complexity would normally suggest something "fast", but I can still see in actual practice the time increase when the input size increases. So have still something to understand about what this being nearly constant in average means in theory and practice  :-)

@Jada Indeed, I got sloppy again. So, I went over the answer in a more rigorous way. The issue was I was "guessing" with the form of the average in Eq. (2) and I overlooked the denominator, which turned out to play an important role. So, of course you were right! Try for values below the threshold; you should, indeed, see constant time on average. Note that the variance is quite high, and that in practice, there might be other hidden complexity factors in a practical implementation, which, when the main computation becomes constant can become more apparent. Very interesting problem! :)

It is. I have never seen that kind of interesting derivation you presented here, but the final results seem to be a geometric kind of series with Bq as rate. In my case, the pruning rate seems to be perfectly balancing or even winning over the spanning factor B. Also, I believe the constant overhead which might be around O(n^3) probably plays the lion role and hides the real asymptotic result, which actually may even be an exponential decay sort of thing (not sure how would that be called in the canonic theory) .

@Jada Makes sense. In my experiments I just run a simple simulation of the number of nodes with truly i.i.d. pruning, which is more that you can claim in practice (as sub-nodes are more related to the current node). My code should be retrievable by typing in python:
import base64,gzip;print(gzip.decompress(base64.a85decode(b'+,^C)L_VIR!rm+50b/gi%,?,^2\\H]G=Ae;r3g?o7cm5KJe2gG..MCb0%A?*/lG\x60Ifjh\'!oK-X#hUTu*RN._m?"@V(;/0SpeLue\x60Gi,>FYX$!<"ee=Xr/ohb/M*0tQ"K2T*BmN"f\';=0PXMqQ6Gbht"=i^;t.k"T"pXSn5ZJ5R#5I^o^V8:N7^F/m1dN9f418Kh3o_CU$c"r]96Z5+)0XTuP,ElK@>CrdpBT%bckQt5^!@i3ZLDp6o!!')).decode())

Thank you, Jamis. These are beautiful! Great insight. Thanks a lot for your help and explanations!

I see you revised the answer. Great work! Thank you! Now it seems more in line with what I am observing. O(1) frankly seemed conceptually totally impossible for what I am doing. O(n) seems more plausible, as my survival percentage 1-p is practically 1/B [which is still a more than incredible result for the problem at hand, btw].
